# How to get only value from global variable?

Tags: javascript

```
var test = ["test", "test", "test"];
        
var temp = test;
        
temp[0] = "change";
        
console.log(test); // ["change", "test", "test"]
```

When I copy a global variable to a temporary variable and change the temporary variable, the global variable changes.

I don't want to change the global variable value.
I only want to get the value and use it.

What should I do?

Comment: Use `slice`: `var temp = test.slice(0);`

Comment: `var temp = [...test];`

Comment: you can use this:
```var temp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(test));```
but slice is better